# Magento 1.5 How to programmaticaly change custom order status after creating an invoice

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I Try to update the order status by an observer after creating an invoice on Magento CE 1.5.

I use the event `sales_order_invoice_save_after`. I've created some specific status for the state `processed`. My code works BUT Magento always put an order status after mine, so it `cancels` mine. I Don't know which event use to avoid this issue.

Here is the code of my observer :

```
       public function updateStatusFacture($observer)
   {
         $event = $observer->getEvent();
         $invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();

    $order_update = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderid);

    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_update->getIncrementId());
                $state = 'processing';
                $status = 'expedier';
                $comment = 'Changing state to Processing and status to expedier Status';
                $isCustomerNotified = false;
                $order->setState($state, $status, $comment, $isCustomerNotified);
                $order->save(); 

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've found what was wrong in my code.
To avoid Magento to save status after me. I have to use this event : `sales_order_invoice_save_commit_after` in place of `sales_order_invoice_save_after`

Hope this helps.